# VBA POWERPOINT: Shrink Word pictures from powerpoint

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint

This function works when I use it within a word macro to shrink all images to 9.3cm:

```
Sub ShrinkWordImages()
Dim iShp As InlineShape

For Each iShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    iShp.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    iShp.Width = CentimetersToPoints(9.3)
Next iShp

End Sub
```

But when I try to run it from within a powerpoint macro, referring to a word document (with all references properly in place), the images in the word document just disappear.
From powerpoint I use this, and its the only difference:

```
For Each iShp In wrdDoc.InlineShapes
```

Where wrdDoc has been properly declared and set.

Powerpoint also crashes after the macro finishes.
I tried changing iShp to variant but that didn't help.

**EDIT**: SO I've now established that CentimetersToPoints(9.3) is returning 0 in powerpoint, vs 263 or so in Word. Looking into that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like `CentimetersToPoint` in PowerPoint which you call in your situation. You need to refer to your Word object variable to get the dimension. Maybe like this:

```
Sub CentimetersTo_Word()

    Dim WRD As Object
    Set WRD = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    Debug.Print WRD.centimeterstopoints(10)

End Sub
```

So, simply add your Word Application reference before `CentimetersToPoint`

Answer (score 0):

Just made my own method...and it worked.

```
Function CmToPt(pt As Single) As Single
CmToPt = pt * 28.35
End Function
```

Not sure why the normal one wasnt working but this did the trick.